# I'm doing model selection using DIC and WAIC. Can they be used to compare different models?

Tags: bayesian, waic, dic

I'm comparing fitted models using the same dataset.

The Models I am tweaking are Logit, Probit and a variation of Probit(Binary models).

I can use DIC and WAIC to make these comparisons.

Do you have a bibliographic reference that provides arguments for your answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking whether those criteria can be used to compare two different models with different datasets, covariates, responses, etc? WAIC of economic data analysis is 'A' and that of environmental data analysis is 'B'. Then compare 'A' and 'B'? If so, I would say no.

Comment: No. I'm asking for models fitted to the same dataset.